# Specific Value for an Initial Condition in a For Loop

Tags: matlab

Basically I have a loop that goes from i=1:1000. I have something like this.

```
for i=1:1000
  y(i) = rho*y(i-1) + u(i);
```

u here is drawing from a normal with mean 0 and var. 1. I have to set the value of y(0)=0. That is in the loop when i=1, the rho*y(0) part has to equal zero and so the value that the process would take when i=1 will just be u(i). How can I set y(0)=0?

Thanks

Comment: Array index starts at 1 in Matlab, not 0. So start the loop at 2 and impose y(1) = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following - set the first element of **y** to be the first element of **u** then iterate starting at i=2

```
y(1) = u(1);
for i=2:1000
   y(i) = rho*y(i-1) + u(i); 
end
```

Comment: Thanks Geoff. That worked. However, I have a second loop after that which iterates on the columns and i wasn't sure how to modify it. Here is what i have: y(1)=u(1);
for i=2:1000
  y(i) = rho*y(i-1) + u(i);
  for j=1:1000
      y(i,j)=rho*y(i-1,j)+u(i,j);
end; How can I change the second loop to reflect the initial condition.

Comment: So if y(1,1) = u(1,1), can we assume that all elements in the first row of **y** are identical to all elements in the first row of **u**?  If so, then just replace y(1) = u(1); with y(1,:) = u(1,:);